# Element type is invalid when creating DragDropContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

Given the following....

```
var root2 = <div />;

var AppDnD = ReactDnD.DragDropContext(ReactDnDMultiBackend.default(RDMBHTML5toTouch.default))(root2);

ReactDOM.render(root2, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I get...

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `DragDropContext(Component)`.

and...

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. Check the render method of
>   `DragDropContext(Component)`

The null mentioned in the warning seems to be a result of the following generated code...

```
React.createElement(AppDnD, null)
```

How do I fix this?

When did Javascript get so sophisticated?

Libraries are basic...

```
   <script src="~/lib/ReactDnD.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/ReactDnDMultiBackend.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/RDMBHTML5toTouch.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DragDropContext` wants a component rather than an element.

Thus, for example, given...

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (<div />);
    }
};
```

Instead of...

```
var root2 = <MyComponent/>;

var AppDnD = ReactDnD.DragDropContext(ReactDnDMultiBackend.default(RDMBHTML5toTouch.default))(root2);

ReactDOM.render(root2, document.getElementById('content'));
```

... one does...

```
var AppDnD = ReactDnD.DragDropContext(ReactDnDMultiBackend.default(RDMBHTML5toTouch.default))(MyComponent);

ReactDOM.render(<AppDnD />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Answers should be (a bit more complete)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer] than restating the error. Please at least _try_ to offer some sample code that may solve the problem

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Updated.